# Shortcut or command line to connect and disconnect third screen in Windows

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors, batch-file, shortcuts

I have two monitors and one TV connected to same computer with Windows 10. I know I can choose to extend or duplicate, or not, to second screen doing WIN + P, but that doesn't work for a third screen.

Its a laptop with Intel HD 630 + Nvidia GT 1050 Ti but Im pretty sure it only uses the HD 630 for normal displays. It also has an external graphics card using DisplayLink. TV is connected to HDMI on laptop while two monitors are connected via the external card/hub

For a while I disconnected and connected the HDMI cable manually but that was a mess and not a good solution.

Right now what I do is to open Display settings, select the screen, scroll down to the drop down menu with the display options and choose *Disconnect this display* in order to disconnect it. And then repeat but choose *Extend desktop to this display* to connect it again. I have to do this a few times a day and its slightly irritating to have to do so much for such an easy thing.

I would like to be able to create a shortcut or a bat file or similar that disconnects the third screen, the TV, when I double click it. And another that connects/extends it. Or make it keyboard shortcuts or anything similar. But even after searching the web for days I couldn't find a solution.

Can anybody here help me out please? How can I make it so that I don't have to open settings each time?

Edit:

This should fix it for anyone with similar problems.

With the freeware MultiMonitorTool it's quite easy:

MultiMonitorTool.exe /disable 1

MultiMonitorTool.exe /enable 2 3

MultiMonitorTool.exe /switch 3

MultiMonitorTool.exe /disable \.\DISPLAY2

Source: [How can I enable/disable monitors from the command-line?](https://superuser.com/questions/308154/how-can-i-enable-disable-monitors-from-the-command-line)

Unfortunately my TV can not be enabled again via command line using MultiMonitorTool for some reason. But at least I can now disable it using a shortcut.

Update

**I have made a new question here regarding why I can not enable the TV display:**

[How to enable TV display with MultiMonitorTool or similar?](https://superuser.com/questions/1540975/how-to-enable-tv-display-with-multimonitortool-or-similar)

Comment: Make and model of graphics card? There may be a setting (hotkey) in the card software.

Comment: Its a laptop with Intel HD 630 + Nvidia GT 1050 Ti but Im pretty sure it only uses the HD 630 for normal displays. It also has an external graphics card using DisplayLink. TV is connected to HDMI on laptop while two monitors are connected via the external card/hub.

Comment: Have you tried using a macro recorder which lets you record and play your keystrokes and mouse ? see some options here: [https://www.prohavit.com/blog/8-free-macro-recorder-automate-traditional-mouse-keyboard/] - you can also do your own search for "windows record mouse and keyboard"

Comment: @1NN I will check it out, thanks. But your link gives me 
Oops, This Page Could Not Be Found!

Comment: Macro recorder doesn't work for this purpose. It might work for a lot of other things but unfortunately it failed every time I tested

Comment: I tried the Multimonitortool by NIrsoft and I can successfully disconnect the Tv with MultiMonitorTool.exe /disable\\.\DISPLAY1 but I can not connect it again with MultiMonitorTool.exe /enable \\.\DISPLAY1 for some reason. Like once its disconnected it cant be connected again except from settings...