# How to enable TV display with MultiMonitorTool or similar?

Tags: windows, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi, tv

I have two monitors and one TV connected to same computer with Windows 10.

[image]

*An image I found online to describe the setup*

I know I can choose to extend or duplicate, or not, to second screen doing WIN + P, but that doesn't work for the TV as it is a third display.

I would really like a shortcut so I dont have to open display setting each time I want to use the TV as display.

My computer is a laptop with Intel HD 630 + Nvidia GT 1050 Ti but Im pretty sure it only uses the HD 630 normally. It also has an external graphics card usb hub using DisplayLink drivers. TV is connected to HDMI on laptop while two monitors are connected via the external hub. The TV is a Samsung smart TV.

With the freeware [MultiMonitorTool](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/multi_monitor_tool.html) it's quite easy to make a command line command that I can save as a shortcut that disables the TV:

[image]

```
MultiMonitorTool.exe /disable 1
```

This disables the display perfectly just as I want. (1 being the monitor number of the TV)

Unfortunately the TV display can not be enabled again via command line using MultiMonitorTool for some reason using:

```
MultiMonitorTool.exe /enable 1
```

If I run the enable command nothing happens.

(When making tests on other two monitors I can enable them with this command so its a problem that is specific for the TV)

If I manually open Windows display settings I can select the display, scroll down and choose "Extend to this display" to enable it.

[image]

*I open display settings and there it is...*

[image]

*Selecting "Extend..." enables the TV display again*

[image]

*Now the display is enabled, and can be disabled with the shortcut again*

My question is, why doesnt it work to enable the TV and what can I do to enable it via command line instead of having to go to settings each time?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for
[MultiMonitorTool](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/multi_monitor_tool.html)
contains several warnings about disabling monitors by their position,
as this may change the position.
It seems to me that once monitor `5` was disabled, it is no longer there
to be re-enabled.

The workaround advised in the documentation is to use instead the commands of
`SaveConfig` and `LoadConfig` in order to change the configuration in such cases.

Comment: Yes I did already try this but unfortunately it didnt work either. Thanks for the reply though! That said, I will try it again soon just to really make sure Im not wrong.

Comment: Just tried it again. Loading the configuration does not enable the display again, sadly.

Comment: The commands `/turnoff` and `/turnon` to toggle the sleep state of the monitors without actually disabling them might work better since the monitors stay where they are. The `enable` problem seems specific to some monitors.

Comment: Yes I tried that too, neither command does anything to the TV. The only command that work is /disable .

Comment: It could have something to do with the fact that its a TV and not a monitor/screen made specifically for PC. I can enable/disable, turn on/off the other two monitors with the commands you suggested. But not enable the TV. I tried all available commands on the MMtool help page.

Comment: I agree that probably this being a TV is the cause of the problem. Try maybe another tool: [WS Display Settings](https://wizardsoft.nl/products/wsdisplaysettings).

Comment: I wasnt able to get that to work correctly either Im afraid @harrymc

Comment: How is the TV connected?

Comment: The TV is connected with a HDMI cable to the HDMI socket of the Laptop

Comment: That may be the problem. Can you try another type of connection than HDMI?

Comment: Unfortunately not