# Computer wont recognize monitor turned off

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, external-display

**Does anyone know what setting might be causing my computer to not recognize when an external monitor is turned off or on?**

I have an HP Elitebook 850 G6 that is connected over DisplayPort to a Dell U2312HM monitor and connected over DisplayPort to an HP E232. With these two monitors, I have a three screen setup:

HP Monitor <-> Laptop Screen <-> Dell Monitor

The issue I am having occurs when I turn off the Dell monitor. For some reason, my computer still makes it possible to have windows (browser window, window explorer, etc.) appear on the turned off Dell monitor. This is an inconvenience, because I do not always have this Dell monitor turned on and often times want it off. If I have any windows on the Dell monitor and turn the monitor off, the windows "stay" on the Dell monitor and I cannot see them from my laptop screen or from the HP monitor screen.

This issue does not occur when I turn off the HP monitor. When the HP monitor is off, all windows that were currently being shown on the HP monitor get pushed to my main laptop screen. Additionally, any new windows that open are unable to be opened on the HP monitor. They are only opened on the available turned on screens.

**Does anyone know how I can change the settings of my Dell monitor to behave more like the HP one?**

Comment: Most people would complain about the HP 'forgetting' to tell the PC it is still there. Just unplug it.

Comment: Which ports are you using to connect these monitors? I don't think this laptop has 2 DP outputs.

Comment: @gronostaj, I am connected to both monitors through a docking station that my laptop is connected to.

Comment: @Tetsujin, unplugging and plugging back in is a little cumbersome. There must be a way to let the PC know when the monitor is on vs. off.

Comment: Part of the monitor connectivity protocol is to keep the computer aware that it's still there. It's not been disconnected, it's in standby & will be back sooner or later. It's expected behaviour. If you don't want that, unplug it. [It is considerably more irritating if the opposite happens & the protocol fails to do its job, believe me.]

Comment: I guess disconnecting in Windows control panel like described [here](https://pureinfotech.com/disconnect-monitor-without-unplugging-windows-10/) basically does what you want for the 3rd monitor. I was also looking for a way to automate it, but unfortunately after that the MultiMonitorTool mentioned [here](https://superuser.com/questions/308154/how-can-i-enable-disable-monitors-from-the-command-line) does not show my TV anymore.

Comment: @Tetsujiny, Do you know what part of the protocol this is? I am pressing the power button on the monitor, I dont want it to be in standby/to exhibit standby behavior.

The other monitor I have, made by HP, does not have this issue. The power and DP cables are both connected at all times, but if I turn this HP monitor off, my computer recognizes this and does not push windows or allow the mouse to move to this monitor.